# End element isn't detected by Stax

Tags: java, xml, stax

I'm reading a XML file same as below:

```
<ts>
    <tr comment="" label="tr1">
        <node order="1" label="" />
    </tr>
</ts>
```

And I expected the below code prints out three `e` on screen:

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader sr = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));

while (sr.hasNext()) {
    int eventType = sr.next();

    if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.START_DOCUMENT) {
        continue;
    } else if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT) {
        System.out.println("e");
    } else if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
        System.out.println("s");
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work! Any ideas on how I can resolve the issue?

*Note: I think it is related to self-closed-tags, for example: `<myTag id="1" />`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code posted in your question produced the three `e` for me which is expected.  I'm using JDK 1.6 on the Mac.

**Demo**

You may want to try running the following code to see which end element event you are missing:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.xml.stream.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader sr = factory.createXMLStreamReader(new FileReader("test.xml"));
        System.out.println(sr.getClass());

        while (sr.hasNext()) {
            int eventType = sr.next();

            if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.START_DOCUMENT) {
                continue;
            } else if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT) {
                System.out.println("End Element:    " + sr.getLocalName());
            } else if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT) {
                System.out.println("Start Element:  " + sr.getLocalName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output I get.

```
class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl
Start Element:  ts
Start Element:  tr
Start Element:  node
End Element:    node
End Element:    tr
End Element:    ts
```

Comment: What happens if do `System.out.println(sr.getLocalName())` inside the if block for `END_ELEMENT`?

Comment: It dosen't go to `END_ELEMENT` block - It never satisfies `if (eventType == XMLStreamReader.END_ELEMENT)`

Comment: Oh! That was a pointless question, at least your test ensured me the problem is not in my stax parsing.

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Windows using JDK 1.7 and am getting the same results as [Blaise Doughan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan):

```
s
s
s
e
e
e
```

I don't think it has to do with the `<node order="1" label="" />` since the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#next%28%29) states that:

> **NOTE**: empty element (such as `<tag/>`) will be reported with two
>   separate events: **START_ELEMENT**, **END_ELEMENT** - This preserves parsing
>   equivalency of empty element to `<tag></tag>`. This method will throw an
>   `IllegalStateException` if it is called after `hasNext()` returns false.

Long shot: maybe some other related code may be causing the weird behavior?